# Disable key entry in Material UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I prevent the user from entering values into my Material UI TextField and force them to user the number stepper instead?

I've tried the following and it does not work.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("0.0");
  const handleKeyPress = () => false;
  return (
    <TextField
      type="number"
      value={value}
      variant="outlined"
      inputProps={{
        maxLength: 13,
        step: "2000"
      }}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work in code sandbox

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("0.0");
 
  return (
    <TextField
      type="number"
      value={value}
      variant="outlined"
      inputProps={{
        maxLength: 13,
        step: "2000",
      }}
      onChange={(evt) => setValue(evt.target.value)}
      onKeyPress={(e)=>{e.preventDefault();return false}}
    />
  );
}
```